# How to get data from one Service Provider to another Service Provider using the obtained SAML assertion?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I have 3 Salesforce orgs (IDP, SP1 and SP2) and have set up SSO where IDP is my Identity-Provider and SP1 and SP2 are 2 Service-Providers. Using SP1-initiated SSO login, the user gets authenticated in IDP org and returns SAML assertion in response to SP1.

Now my requirement is when the user is redirected to SP1 from IDP after authentication, I want to fetch some case related data from SP2 and display in SP1 without making the user login into SP2.

Can anyone help me understand how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

When you receive SAML assertion from IDP to SP1, it is mere confirming the identity. That assertion is not an authentication token (Session id) so you cannot login directly into SP2.

The only way for you to connect to sp2 from sp1 is to integrate sp2 with sp1 using username/password or oauth and use the apis to fetch data.

Comment: Thanks realfire for responding to my question. I tested with oAuth option and I am able to get the session_id, but how do I verify that when a User hits the services/oauth/token url to get the access_token, my SP2 org is validating that this User is authenticated in the IDP org and if not that User should be redirected to the SP1's login page.